# GET http request from Microcontroller to server (API)

Tags: http, microcontroller, ethernet, lwip, stm32f4

I'm working with a stm32f4 microcontroller using lwip/stack, i use it to controle send http requests via ethernet .
the following code works fine:

```
   sprintf(buffer, "GET /api/callAction?deviceID=80&name=turnOn\r\n");
   strcat(buffer, "Host: 192.168.2.7\r\n");
   strcat(buffer, "Connection: close\r\n");
   strcat(buffer, "\r\n");
```

the problem is when the sever needs authentication like this :

```
 admin:admin@192.168.2.7/api/callAction?deviceID=80&name=turnOn
```

i have tried adding an authorization part to the code :

```
 strcat(buffer, "Host: admin:admin@192.168.2.7\r\n");
```

But the http request doesn't work .

Any ideas? 
ps: im using Keil ARM /stm32f4 / lwip stack
   Server:  Fibaro home center lite

Answer (score 1):

Have a read here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

you want to pass this string

```
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the Base64 version of `username:password`

for example, if username is `Aladdin` and password is `OpenSesame` then you have to Base64 encode the string `Aladdin:OpenSesame` which results into `QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`

you string is then:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

Just strcat it as you do for all the other stuff:

```
strcat(buffer, "Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l\r\n");
```